# how mongodb determines majority if a node fails during write operation

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose i have set w=majority as write concern and a node fails during a write operation,

will the majority be changed according to the currently alive nodes?

i.e., Suppose there are 3 nodes. Now the majority is 2. And if a node fails during a write operation, will the majority be decreased or will it remain same and wait for the node to come up?

Comment: If you have 3 nodes and one fails, two still form a majority. It's a replica set configuration majority, not a majority of alive nodes. So if one node fails, acknowledgment from the master and the remaining active replica still form a majority. The operation will not block for the 3rd node to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of a replica set is determined based on replica set configuration, not its current running state.

In other words, if you have a three node replica set configured, then majority is always two.  If one node is offline, two is still the majority.  If two nodes are offline, two is still majority and cannot be satisfied until one of the offline nodes comes back online.